# Unable to download file document on browser?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP page with some back end Java logic written to it. The page basically displays a PDF document on the browser when I paste the URL on the browser. The URL is in this format:

```
http://localhost:8080/repository/file/view/viewPDF.jsp?nodeID=27455
```

When I paste the URL, it's able to display the docoment properly but at the same time I want it to automatically download the document. By the browser's behaviour, it should have a download icon on the bottom left of the browser.

My only problem is it doesn't download at all but only shows the PDF document.

My viewPDF.JSP:

```
<%

///This section loads the PDF document on the browser

    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    boolean debug = true;
    try {


        String snodeid = request.getParameter("nodeID");
        long nodeid = Long.parseLong(snodeid);

        Pdfinfo pdf = PPFacade.getPDFInfo(nodeid);
        String pdfpath = pdf.getFfullpath();
        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("=============== PDF STREAM ================");
            System.out.println("pdfpath = " + pdfpath);
        }

        //int len = (int)new File("D://test.pdf").length();
        int len = (int) new File(pdfpath).length();
        response.setContentLength(len);
        byte[] buf = new byte[len];
        FileInputStream pdfin = new FileInputStream(pdfpath);
        pdfin.read(buf);
        pdfin.close();
        OutputStream pdfout = response.getOutputStream();
        pdfout.write(buf, 0, len);
        pdfout.flush();


        if (debug) {
            System.out.println("=============== END PDF STREAM ================");
        }
        ///End of section

        ///////Automatically download file attachment


        InitialContext ctx1 = new InitialContext();
        FileFacadeLocal fileFacade1 = (FileFacadeLocal) ctx1.lookup("java:comp/env/file");
        SettingsFacadeLocal settingsFacade1 = (SettingsFacadeLocal) ctx1.lookup("java:comp/env/settings");
        Modlattr mod = settingsFacade1.get("ROOTFOLDER");
        if (mod == null) {
            throw new Exception("Unable to obtain system properties.");
        }
        String folder = mod.getAtval() + "/download/";

        int count = 1;
        if (count == 1) {
            //  long fileID = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("f0"));
            Fmedia fmedia = fileFacade1.get_file(nodeid);
            if (fmedia == null) {
                throw new Exception(fileFacade1.getMsg());
            }
            String OriginalName = fmedia.getFdesc();

            response.setContentType("application/x-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + OriginalName + "\"");

            ServletOutputStream servletOutput = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream srcFile = new FileInputStream(fmedia.getFfulpath() + fmedia.getFgname());

            byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = srcFile.read(buff)) != -1) {
                servletOutput.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            srcFile.close();
            servletOutput.close();


        } else {
            long nodeID = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("nodeID"));
            Fmediainfo finfo = fileFacade.GetInfo(nodeID);
            if (finfo == null) {
                throw new Exception("Unable to locate file information.");
            }

            List Files = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                long fileID = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("f" + i));
                Fmedia fmedia = fileFacade.get_file(fileID);
                if (fmedia == null) {
                    throw new Exception(fileFacade.getMsg());
                }
                Files.add(fmedia);
            }

            byte[] buf1 = new byte[1024];
            String zipFileUUID = folder + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileUUID));

            Iterator i = Files.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                Fmedia fmedia = (Fmedia) i.next();
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fmedia.getFfulpath() + fmedia.getFgname());

                // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
                zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fmedia.getFoname()));

                int len1;
                while ((len1 = in.read(buf1)) > 0) {
                    zipOut.write(buf1, 0, len1);
                }

                // Complete the entry
                zipOut.closeEntry();
                in.close();

            }
            zipOut.close();


            response.setContentType("application/x-download");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + finfo.getFmrefno() + ".zip\"");

            ServletOutputStream servletOutput = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream srcFile = new FileInputStream(zipFileUUID);

            byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = srcFile.read(buff)) != -1) {
                servletOutput.write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            srcFile.close();
            servletOutput.close();

            File zFile = new File(zipFileUUID);
            zFile.delete();

        }







        /////////////////
```

The code might be a little bit long but I just think it's better to include them.The only important section is the 2nd part of the code which is responsible for downloading the file.

I have tried debugging it and it does pass the correct values, so now I am not sure why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the browser to download your file instead of opening the pdf, you could try setting the response type to application/force-download.

```
response.setContentType("application/force-download");
```

Comment: You've set content type twice in your code. Are you sure you tried replacing the last occurrence? (You don't need to set it multiple times though)

Comment: which part did i set twice?

Comment: response.setContentType(). Thrice actually, not just twice.

Comment: But two of them are in if else statement and one for loading pdf doc

Comment: You have only one servlet, and one servlet response. Therefore setting the content type once is sufficient.

Comment: OK i deleted the first section, instead i want to just automatically download it when i paste the url and not display anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190002/discussion-between-daredevil-and-nutella).